# ASP.NET config files per env or per developer

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web-config

This might have already answered somewhere else but I couldnt find the exact answer; so apologies

I know it is possible to have web.config or any config file per developer or per env such Robert or John or between Dev, UAT and PRD but I dont know how it can be achieved in Visual Studio 2010.

Currently I have various settings stored in the config file and then depending where we are deploying or who is working; we pick the respective setting using a switch key/value.

but at deployment time I have to swap out values such dev becomes uat when deployed to uat or dev becomes live when deployed to PRD.

however, a neater solution would be to have config per env so just switch or pick the correct config at the time of deployment?

Can anyone please help/advise? if you need more info then please let me know.

Comment: You need Web.config transformation. A good (basic) start would be [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Simon; I have checked the suggested page and it does look like something I can use. Cheers